# Netlogo code for sorting agents in lists according to their properties

Tags: list, sorting, netlogo

I am trying to sort my agents [industries] into a list and make many further lists based on that initial list sequence. 
Each industry has two properties [bid-cap] and [bid-price]. I want first, a sorted list [low-bid-ind] of agents according to their ascending bid-prices, then I want to use the same sequence and fetch the values of [bid-cap] and make a list [low-cap-list], then I want to fetch bid-price for same sequence as [low-bid-ind] list and save it in a list [low-cap-list]. I only make this list so I can make another list with cumulative sum values of the [bid-cap] of agents. 
Following is my code. There's an error : LPUT expected input to be a list but got the number 0 instead. 
But it doesn't show where the error occurs in the code.

```
  set agentlist-low [] 
  set low-bid-ind [] 
  set low-cap-list []
  set sum-low-bid []

  set agentlist-low industries with [group = 0] 
  set low-bid-ind sort-on [bid-price] agentlist-low

  foreach low-bid-ind 
  [ the-industry -> 
    set low-cap-list lput ([bid-cap] of the-industry) low-cap-list ]

  let sum-low 0
  let m 0 
  foreach low-bid-ind
    [set m m + 1
      set sum-low sum-low + item m low-cap-list
      set sum-low-bid lput sum-low sum-low-bid ]
  print sum-low-bid
```

Can anyone help with this problem? 
I have looked at Netlogo help and other questions on the internet but I am unable to find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the error you are getting.  Are you sure that you are setting `low-cap-list` and `sum-low-bid` to empty lists in your actual code? That kind of error normally comes when `lput` is given a list which has not been initialized, as uninitialized variables in NetLogo are set to 0.

But more generally, NetLogo has a `map` operation that eliminates the need for looping over lists in most cases. So the loop

```
foreach low-bid-ind 
  [ the-industry -> 
    set low-cap-list lput ([bid-cap] of the-industry) low-cap-list ]
```

can be written more economically as

```
 set low-cap-list map [the-industry -> [bid-cap] of the-industry] low-bid-ind
```

and the code segment

```
 let sum-low 0
  let m 0 
  foreach low-bid-ind
    [set m m + 1
      set sum-low sum-low + item m low-cap-list
      set sum-low-bid lput sum-low sum-low-bid ]
```

can be written as a single line

```
set sum-low-bid map [m -> sum sublist low-cap-list 0 (m + 1)] range (length low-bid-ind)
```

`map` creates a list by performing the operation in brackets on each item in the list it is given.  In the latter case, that input list is simply the numbers from 0 to the length of the low-bid-ind list.